# Javascript timer initializes on each postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, timer

This is my script on aspx page which is used to initialize timer on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function display() {

            var hours = document.getElementById('<%=HidH.ClientID %>');

            var minutes = document.getElementById('<%=HidM.ClientID %>');

            var seconds = document.getElementById('<%=HidS.ClientID %>');



            if (hours.value == 00 && minutes.value == 00 && seconds.value == 00) {

                PageMethods.ReturnQuestionId(1);

                alert("Time Given For this Test is Over");


                var newwindow = window.location.replace("frmResultCheck.aspx");

                if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
                return false;

            }
            if (minutes.value < 10) {
                minutes.value = minutes.value;
            }
            if (seconds.value <= 00) {
                if ((hours.value == 00) && (minutes.value == 00))
                    seconds.value = 00;
                else {
                    seconds.value = 60;
                    minutes.value -= 01;
                }
            }

            if (minutes.value <= 00) {
                if ((hours.value < 00) && (seconds.value < 00)) {
                    hours.value = minutes.value = seconds.value = 00;
                }
                else {
                    if ((hours.value == 00) && (seconds.value == 00))
                        hours.value = seconds.value = 00;
                    if ((hours.value > 00) && (minutes.value < 00)) {
                        minutes.value = 59;
                        hours.value -= 01;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ((minutes.value <= -01) || (hours.value <= -01)) {
                if (hours.value <= -01) {
                    minutes.value = 00;
                    hours.value += 01;
                }
                else

                    minutes.value -= 01;
                seconds.value = 00;
                minutes.value += 01;
            }
            else
                if (seconds.value > 00)
                    seconds.value -= 01;

            if (hours.value.length < 2) {
                hours.value = "0" + hours.value;

            }
            if (minutes.value.length < 2) {
                minutes.value = "0" + minutes.value;

            }
            if (seconds.value.length < 2) {
                seconds.value = "0" + seconds.value;

            }

            document.getElementById('counter').value = hours.value + ":" + minutes.value +


 ":" + seconds.value;

            setTimeout("display()", 1000);



            if (document.getElementById('btnSubmit').onclick == true)



                document.getElementById('counter').value = "";
        }

        display();
    </script>
```

This is my aspx.cs page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
int factor;
  if (factor >= 60)
                {
                    int b = factor / 60;
                    factor = factor % 60;
                    string time = Convert.ToString(b + ":" + factor);

                    if (factor < 10)
                    {
                        timer = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, @"h\:m", null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        timer = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, @"h\:mm", null);
                    }
                }
                else if (factor > 9 && factor < 60)
                {
                    timer = TimeSpan.ParseExact(factor.ToString(), "mm", null);
                }
                else
                {
                    timer = TimeSpan.ParseExact("0" + factor.ToString(), "mm", null);


                }
                HidH.Value = Convert.ToString(timer.Hours);



                HidM.Value = Convert.ToString(timer.Minutes);



                HidS.Value = Convert.ToString(timer.Seconds);
}
```

Everytime i click next button on page, timer goes back to the same time at which i clicked the next button. I want my timer to go on continuously even on postbacks.

Comment: Can you explain the logic in the question, you have provided the code already which is good.. **a little logic explanation will help us to understand better**..

Comment: Alright, the above code is responsible for a countdown timer in a page.When i am clicking on the next button on the page to move to a new location the javascript timer initializes to the same time at which i clicked on the next button.Suppose, the time was 01:09:55 when i clicked the next button ,after which the page loads ,but when the new page is loaded , the timer goes back to 01:09:55 instead of the time taken to load the page.The timer should be at 01:09:42 or something like that.

Comment: you can use session here, put the tracker value in hidden field and read that value on onload of DOM

Comment: @Rohit are you open to Ajax. Typically postback will refresh the entire page by this javascript variables can't be maintained since the page loads again. You can submit the answer's selection alone in Ajax. By this you can retain JS variable values.

Comment: Can you please be more specific regarding the above comment..

Comment: Yes i am open to Ajax @Sridhar..Let me try this concept.

Comment: @RohitSingh Definitely try Ajax, definitely worth it. Also if you have no constraints start using Jquery, why should you use it ..  here is a link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs)

Answer (score 0):

In your C# Page_Load code, check if it is post-back before initializing the values. Initialize only if it is a first time load (i.e. `!IsPostBack`).
Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Your initializing code here
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result and the current result? Is there any error?

Comment: On page load the time was 01:09:52 but when i clicked on the next button which causes postback the time was again initialized to 01:09:52 instead of time being in the decreasing order.

Comment: Your javascript expression `if (document.getElementById('btnSubmit').onclick == true)` is incorrect. `onclick` property will never return a `boolean`. It will either return a `function` or `null`. You can achieve that using `if (document.getElementById('btnSubmit').onclick)`

Comment: So what should be the syntax to make the timer work?

Comment: No success P5Coder...:-(

Comment: Your `if (factor >= 60)` is totally ineffective because `factor` is not initialized and only declared. Isn't your compiler giving you any error?

Comment: No please don't be confused by that. I am maintaining the value of factor on the basis of count of rows of a datatable. Value is assigned to factor.